Can a projective 2-dimensional variety have zero $b_2$?
Compkex irreducible projective varieties, which are smooth, have nonzero even Betti numbers https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122689/betti-numbers-of-proper-nonprojective-varieties. Can it be true that for a non-smooth, but normal, projective 2-dimensional variety has zero $b_2$?

No, this cannot be true. On any projective variety, for a curve $C$ and an ample divisor $A$ we have $A \cdot C >0$. So the class of $C$ in $H_2$ can't be zero (or torsion).
